# Android how to view long string in logcat

Tags: java, android, hashmap, logcat, linkedhashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String,String>` that is fairly long (not an issue) and I'm trying to make sure things look correct before I use the data inside it. To do this I'm trying to just attempting to do this `Log.v("productsFromDB",products.toString())` but in the `LogCat` It shows about 1/3 of it. Is there a way to output the entire map?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Logcat can only show about 4000 characters. So you need to call a recursive function to see the entire hashmap. Try this function:

```
public static void longLog(String str) {
    if (str.length() > 4000) {
        Log.d("", str.substring(0, 4000));
        longLog(str.substring(4000));
    } else
        Log.d("", str);
}
```

Comment: how to remove  " [ 12-09 12:34:09.886 27901:27901 V/ " all time?i want to see chunk of json but there are v and date .i want to get full chunk with out  v and date.any way?

Comment: @Suman I dont think it can be done though I would like to be proved wrong

Comment: ,thanks for your reply.I want see whole log without time or type or any thing else.mean when i copy from log then some some time and type are added into string,